# Failed to get screen image buffer by using iosurface in iOS8

Tags: ios

Recently, I was making an app which could record the screen on the iPad. I was using IOSurface to do this. 
`CARenderServerRenderDisplay(0, CFSTR("LCD"), IOSurfaceRef, 0, 0)`is the method to get the image buffer from the screen. Actually, this method works perfectly in iOS 7, but it just failed in iOS 8 (Getting a black screen).

By the way, I've changed several methods to do this, and they worked successfully on iPad Air. However, it caused bad performance like low fps when it came to the old iPad like iPad 3 and iPad 4 because the hardware couldn't hold the writing speed.

This problem has bothered me for several weeks. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I was thirsty for the reason why the method on top will get the black screen from iPad in iOS 8. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Which methods did you change? I also need to record the screen in iOS 8. Please tell me! Thanks.

Comment: did u get any solution please tell us